# Pull sys data from multiple DBs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a large number of extended properties that house where our stored procedures pull data from. 
Example: Stored Procedure 1 uses 6 source tables.

I have a few thousand of these. I would like to see if there is a way I can pull some statistics from the source tables for some general health DB reporting. Simple things like row counts, table size, last updated, etc...

I can get these things easily enough if I string the results and use sp_executesql commands. Does anyone have a way to get this in code without using string SQL?

This is my current output

```
ObjectID    Name       TableName    Schema    DB
123456      Procedure1 Table1       dbo       Database1 
123456      Procedure1 Table2       Schema1   Database2
123456      Procedure1 Table3       dbo       Database3
123456      Procedure1 Table4       dbo       Database4
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SSMS 2012